# Update dictionary value and get the previous one in C#

Tags: java, c#, performance, dictionary

I've came to C# world from Java background.

I need to update the value in a map/dictionary and get the previous value (or null if there were none). I would do the following in Java:

```java
String oldValue = myMap.put(key, newValue);
someFunction(oldValue, newValue);
```

In C# I use `Dictionary`, but I've found no method to get the previous value on update. So far I need to perform 2 lookups to accomplish this, which I see not very optimal in terms of performance and lines of code

```
string oldValue = null;
myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, oldValue);
myDictionary[key] = newValue;
SomeFunction(oldValue, newValue);
```

Is there an easier way to update value and get the previous one?

Comment: Your method is the right way to go about it. Perhaps write a quick function for it so you can reuse?

Comment: It's not the main point of the question, but anyway : `var oldValue = null;` doesn't make sense. If you initialize a variable with null, either declare it the correct type, or cast the null to the correct type, but `var` can't be inferred by the compiler otherwise.

Comment: @ekaerovets, doing lookup by key in a dictionary is a very quick operation. don't worry about the overhead of doing so. If you are worried, remember the first rule of Code Optimisation: Don't.  (http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: Just write the helper method which is going to read, update and return the old value.

Comment: @AndrewP actually two lines of boilerplate code bother me more, than the extra lookup. Anyway, I got the idea.

Comment: dictionary look up performance mostly depends on performance of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` that is implemented for key object. since keys are string here, pass `StringComparer.Ordinal` to dictionary constructor for better performance. also dictionary that has not been filled to its maximum capacity will perform demonstrably faster. if you are doing few look ups you shouldn't even care about these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue UpdateAndGet<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue newVal)
    {
        TValue oldVal;
        dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out oldVal);
        dictionary[key] = newVal;

        return oldVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `UpdateAndGetValue` would be a better name?

Comment: And returnning null instead of exception would be more preferable. All the rest is perfect.

Comment: @NetMage. Maybe. :)

Comment: @ekaerovets. It depends on what you want. If you want default you should use default(TValue).

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the right thing if the key is not found in the dictionary. It won't set the new value. Also as already said returning null if its not found is the required behaviour, not throwing an exception.

Comment: I've changed to using default value instead of Exception.

Comment: @Valerii isn't oldValue initialized with default value at `TValue oldVal`?

Comment: @ekaerovets. Yes. Good idea.

Comment: No it's not (there's no = sign) however it IS set to the default value by TryGetValue via the out parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the built in `AddOrUpdate` method of the "thread-safe" `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` class which inherits from `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` like:

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Country> countries = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Country>();

public void Main()
{
    Country poland = new Country { Name = "Poland", Capital = "Krakow" };
    countries[poland.Name] = poland; 
    // oops lets update the right capital:
    poland.Capital = "Warsaw";

    myList.AddOrUpdate(poland.Name, poland, (key, oldValue) => 
                                         {
                                             Console.WriteLine($"The old value was: '{oldValue}'");  
                                             return oldValue; 
                                         });
}

//Output: The old value was: 'Krakow'
```

See more info on [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here as there is no myList, but the update factory for a AddOrUpdate call on ConcurrentDictionary should return the new value, not the old one, otherwise it won't update the dict, so that approach won't work.

Comment: Oh the factory does return the new value, I only demonstrate writing the old value to log

Comment: your code does "return existingVal;"

Answer (score 0):

Starting from .NET 6 you could use the advanced API [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault), and do the `AddOrUpdate` operation with a single key hashing:

```
public static void AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key, TValue value,
    out bool oldValueExists, out TValue oldValue)
{
    ref TValue valueRef = ref CollectionsMarshal
        .GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, key, out oldValueExists);
    oldValue = valueRef;
    valueRef = value;
}
```

This is the signature of the `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault` method:

```
// Gets a reference to a TValue in the specified dictionary,
// adding a new entry with a default value if the key does not exist.
public static ref TValue? GetValueRefOrAddDefault<TKey,TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, TKey key, out bool exists);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of Extension Methods and write one.

Below returns true/false depending on if key is found or not.

```
public static bool UpdateDictionaryAndGetOldValue(this Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key, string newVal, out string oldVal)
{
    oldVal = string.Empty;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out oldVal))
    {
        dict[key] = newVal;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

This returns the old value.

```
public static string UpdateDictionaryAndGetOldValue(this Dictionary<string, string> dict, string key, string newVal)
{
    string oldVal = string.Empty;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out oldVal);
    dict[key] = newVal;
    return oldVal;
}
```

And `TK` and `TV` can be used to make this general.

Comment: Can I make this method generic? E.g. `public static V UpdateAndGet(this Dictionary<K, V> ...` ?

Comment: this extension method, lacks ability to find out if entry with given key exist in dictionary or not. you could use `out` for setting old value and return bool value to indicate if operation succeeded or not.

Comment: ``V oldVal = default(V);``

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I only gave an outline to show the idea. Of course you can make the return type `bool` and do an `out` to actually retrivew the old value.

Comment: The extension method reduces lines of code, but does nothing to help the two lookup inefficiency.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary since OP, asked for the same as java ``myMap.put(key, newValue);`` the answer is exactly the same, since java also doesnt give an indicator if the oldValue was actually found - only return null if it didnt found the entry, but that also is the case if it found the key but the value is null

Comment: @NetMage its not _always_ inefficient. it depends on situation, most of the time I would say its indeed efficient enough.

Comment: It works with generics `        public static TV UpdateAndGetPrevious<TK, TV>(this Dictionary<TK, TV> dictionary, TK key, TV newValue) {            TV oldValue;            dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue);            dictionary[key] = newValue;            return oldValue;        }`

Comment: @Sach too many parameters - in most cases getting null as return value is pretty descriptive

Comment: I don't think this does the right thing. If the key isn't already in the dictionary it just returns false without setting the new value. Also `oldVal = string.Empty;` is completely pointless since the values gets overwritten in the very next line.

Comment: The OP wanted to 'update and get old value' so I assume key not being there is a failure mode for the scenario. You need to assign 'something' to the oldVal if you want to use it as an `out` parameter so it's not completely pointless.